# Running raw complicated queries with sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a peculiar problem. I have a joined query due to the distribution of data in various table. I want to run this as raw sql query using node module for sequelize as alot existing code is associated using sequelize orm. I do not want to use orm here but just a plain raw query.

```
SELECT testmodel.bacode, testmodel2.paopkey from (SELECT ptr.paopkey as paopkey, psgkey.pskey from (SELECT * FROM   pts where paopkey = 4 and ptr_active = 1) ptr,
pt_sg psgkey where ptr.pkey = psgkey.pkey) testmodel2,
pt_act testmodel where testmodel.pskey =  testmodel2.pskey;
```

Any advise if the above query can be run as raw query and the data can be captured as result.
Also when I run the below code with below sequelize code, I get
the error **"_sequelize.default.query is not a function"**

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
async function getTestDataList(opcoKey) {
  const testdata = await Sequelize.query(`SELECT testmodel.bacode, testmodel2.paopkey from (SELECT ptr.paopkey as paopkey, psgkey.pskey from (SELECT * FROM pts where paopkey = 4 and ptr_active = 1) ptr,
  pt_sg psgkey where ptr.pkey = psgkey.pkey) testmodel2,
  pt_act testmodel where testmodel.pskey =  testmodel2.pskey;`, 
  { type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }).then(function (results) {
     // SELECT query - use then
  })
  return toPlain(testdata);
}
```

Dbclient code using sequelize instance is as follows

```
import config from 'config';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
class DataSource { constructor() {this.DBclient = null; } 
initializeDB(dbCredentials) { const dataSource = config.datasource; 
const options = { host: "127.0.0.1", dialect: dataSource.dialect, port: dataSource.port, logging: false, }; 
const { password } = dbCredentials || dataSource; 
this.DBclient = new Sequelize( dataSource.database, "root", "root", options, ); 
} getDBClient() { return this.DBclient; }}export default new DataSource();
```

Comment: [Yes.](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js~sequelize#instance-method-query)

Comment: I get the error ""_sequelize.default.query is not a function""

Comment: You have to create a connection to a database via `new Sequelize(...)`.

Comment: I have done that as well and I get it now _datasource.default.getDBClient.query  is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You should store a created Sequelize connection and use it to call `query` method:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequilize(connection_options_here)

const testdata = await sequelize.query(`SELECT testmodel.bacode, testmodel2.paopkey from (SELECT ptr.paopkey as paopkey, psgkey.pskey from (SELECT * FROM pts where paopkey = 4 and ptr_active = 1) ptr,
  pt_sg psgkey where ptr.pkey = psgkey.pkey) testmodel2,
  pt_act testmodel where testmodel.pskey =  testmodel2.pskey;`, 
  { type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
```

I removed `then` in the above code because there is no need in it thus you use `await`.

Comment: Anatoly, the datasource file actually creates a connection like this this.DBclient = new Sequelize(
      dataSource.database,
      "root",
      "root",
      options,
    );
  }

  getDBClient() {
    return this.DBclient;
  }

Comment: Then show updated code where you use  `getDBClient`

Comment: import config from 'config';import Sequelize from 'sequelize';class DataSource {  constructor() {this.DBclient = null;
  }
  initializeDB(dbCredentials) {
    const dataSource = config.datasource;
    const options = {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      dialect: dataSource.dialect,
      port: dataSource.port,
      logging: false,
    };    const { password } = dbCredentials || dataSource; 
    this.DBclient = new Sequelize(
      dataSource.database,
      "root",
      "root",
      options,
    );  }  getDBClient() {    return this.DBclient;  }}export default new DataSource();

Comment: Please edit your post and add this code there as a formatted one. It's very hard t read it in comments

Comment: Added the formatted code in the original post now.

Comment: Ok, and now show the code where you use `DataSource `